# Minicom: transfer CRLF when hit enter?

Tags: minicom

I have a custom HW which *can* understand commands received over UART.

For this purpose I'm using `minicom` on Linux.

However the HW needs to get `CRLF` after the command to properly recognize it.

How can I ask minicom to **send** CRLF after I hit enter?

(I know I can ask it to add CRLF to incoming lines, but I need the other way here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bring up the menu (Ctrl+A, Z or Alt+Z depending on your settings) there are options `U` and `A` to add CR and LF to the incoming characters received over the wire.  When you select the option, look in the Minicom status bar to see what value is set.

You can press Ctrl+J to send an LF, but that's a bit of a pain as you have to press Enter then Ctrl+J at the end of each line.

I'm not sure of a way to tell Minicom to send CR+LF automatically, but will update this answer if ever I find one.

Comment: A and U are for incoming CR and LF control: "**A**: Toggle 'Add Linefeed' on/off. If it is on, a linefeed is added before every carriage return displayed on the screen. / **U**: Add carriage return to each received line."

Comment: @scruss You're right, I have updated my answer.